# Best way to use ajax front-end?

Tags: ajax, front-end

The question is about which way is the best / easiest way to make a theme with ajax, using admin-ajax.php or normally.
I ask because I see that complicates using admin-ajax.php for everything and use jquery plugin to enable your browser history for example.

that think?

Sorry for my English!!!

Comment: What does normally mean? This is default way in WordPress to use ajax: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and you do not have to use just jQuery. You can enqueue mootools or other js, or just use pure js

Comment: Normally is without using admin-ajax

Comment: admin-ajax is recomended and thoug normal way to use Ajax in WordPress...

Answer (score 4):

Never ever use your theme/plugin files directly for ajax calls, always use `admin-ajax.php`. This is the **only** recommended way of doing ajax to ensure maximum compatibility with wordpress (including future versions) & 3rd party plugins/themes

The best/easiest way depends on the situation & is debatable but i would ask you to use `admin-ajax.php` even if it is hard or inefficient

Comment: the situation is make one theme 100% ajax, posts, pages, search, etc.. but I have one problem to implement wp_query with admin-ajax

Comment: @user11721 - if you have a specific issue with using `WP_Query` with `admin-ajax.php`, then ask a new question with details of that specific issue.

Comment: agree, but my question in using admin-ajax is exactly how I do, because since the function ajax_call for example not find out how to return the page I want to visit. Since it I consider it to make a WP_Query and not return the body_class , wp_footer (for scripts that usage on some pages) and one problem I encounter is with next-page of the post, which pagename=post/second page not works.